# Записать картинки на сервер url

Tags: url, android, изображения

Здравствуйте. у каждого пользователя есть аватар. я уже сделал выбор аватара из галереи и также можно сделать фото. Потом мне нужно чтоб пользователь видел не только свой аватар, но и всех остальных. То есть я думаю, после выбора аватара, нужно сохранить этот файл на сервер, чтоб другие могли скачать по url этот файл. Как скачать по url я знаю, а как записать на сервер картинки?

Comment: Всё зависит от сервера.

Comment: объясните пожалуйся что именно?

Comment: @Firespirit на какой сервер собираешься картинки заливать? Ознакомься с документацией, как он картинки принимает. Например, я писал приложение на Андроиде для VK и там чётко в документации написано, что фото нужно отправлять POST запросом на определённый URL. Ну, а после этого уже я начал смотреть, как в Андроиде можно передать картинку POST запросом. А наобум отсылать куда-то картинку смысла нет. Сервер может не принять. Возможно нужна предварительная авторизация. Ещё раз напишу. Всё зависит от того, как настроен сервер на приём картинок.

Comment: я сам настраиваю сервер, могу делать все что хочу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Отправить post-запросом и обработать
       на сервере.
2. По ftp

Comment: в каком виде отправить POST запросом картинку? можно ли потом "это" записать в базу? типо сделать из картинки текст или как?

Comment: Отправляешь post-запросом картинку как массив байт. Там у битмапа прям метод такой вроде есть toByteArray()

Comment: а массив байт как в базу записать? всмысле как его хранить? просто я не знаю в sql какой тип подходит под массив байт,я знаю только текст, варкар, интегер, дабл, а массив байт в sql как хранить?

Comment: @Suvitruf, не очень хорошо хранить картинки в базе, лучше хранить на диске и раздавать напрямую, а базе хранить пути.

Comment: а как хранить на диске? называть картинку по имени пользователя?

Comment: @Firespirit, ну это уже сами думайте. Мне обычно не важно как хранить на сервере.
Саму картинку можно с каким угодно (но уникальным) именем хранить, а в базе делать связку этой картинки с юзером.
При добавлении картинки, делаете запись  в БД (получите уникальный идентификатор записи), а саму картинку сохраняйте на диск с этим уникальным идентификаторм.